# Which version of squid should I choose?

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

There are 3 squid releases in squid's official website: 2.7, 3.0 and 3.1.

I am confused, [which one should I choose](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages)?

Comment: If you have no specific requirements, go with the newest 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to go with 3.1 if you want to proxy IPv6 traffic.  Otherwise, I would install the latest version packaged for your distribution.

Comment: is there any suggestion about stable or performance different of these  squid versions.

Comment: All versions are stable.  3.1 is quite new, and 3.0 was a major rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Choose whichever one has packages in your chosen distributions repo.  Preferably ones that get maintained.  Or just choose the latest ;)

Answer (score 0):

With 2.x versions of Squid certain interactive features, such as Google's instant search do not work correctly. Hopefully, you are using a recent enough distro where 3.x is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Squid 3.0 has NTLM auth using LDAP, that is very very cool if you have a windows network behind squid.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case. There are a number of features that exist in 2.7 and not yet in 3.x because they were in part developed in parallel. I'd start reading at the [Squid 2.7](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Squid-2.7) link and compare on the functionality you need. One of the reasons I've stuck with 2.7 is because of [StaleWhileRevalidate](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StaleWhileRevalidate) but most users are looking more for controlling content and 3.x tends to do that better.